# understanding of the rank-2 tensor as an integral kernel

Tags: reference-request, integration

> Let $G\subset{\mathbb R}^m$ be a nonempty compact and Jordan measurable set that coincides with the closure of its interior. Let $K:G\times G\to{\mathbb C} $ be a continuous function. Then we can define an linear operator $A:C(G)\to C(G)$ as
>   $$
> (A\phi)(x):=\int_G K(x,y)\phi(y)dy,\quad x\in G.
> $$
>   If the kernel $K$ is defined and continuous for all $x,y\in G\subset{\mathbb R}^m, x\neq y$, and there exist positive constants $M$ and $\alpha\in(0,m]$ such that 
>   $$
> |K(x,y)|\leq M|x-y|^{\alpha-m}, \quad x,y\in G, x\neq y,
> $$
>   the kernel $K$ is called **weakly singular**.

The definitions above are from *Linear Integral Equations* by Rainer Kress.

Here are my **questions**:

If the kernel is a rank-2 tensor, for example, the Oseen tensor in this [wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow) about Stokes flow, can I define the concept that "the kernel is weakly singular"? If the answer is YES, how should I do it? One possible way I think is using some norm of matrices.